# Rails4でpolymorphicなモデルに対するhas_manyのエイリアス名を変更するには？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

polymorphicなcommentモデルがあるとします。
areaモデルを作成し

```
has_many :comments, as: :commendable
```

とすると

```
@area.comments
```

でアクセスできますよね？

これを、`@area.messages`や`@area.bbs`など
`comments`以外の名前を利用してアクセスするには
どうすればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class_name を指定します。

```
has_many :messages, :as => :commendable, :class_name => "Comment"
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！とても助かりました！